# Why do I get "error C2006: '#include' : expected a filename, found 'identifier' "?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, header, include, compiler-errors

My source code in Visual C++ Express 2008 is as follows :

```
#include “stdafx.h”
#include <iostream>
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
std::cout << “Hello world!\n”;
return 0;
}
```

I'm using the book, Visual C++ 2008,by Ivor Horton

.These are the errors that I'm encountering.How do I get rid of the errors ?

> 1>e:\my documents\visual studio 2008\projects\hello\hello\hello.cpp(1) : error C2006: '#include' : expected a filename, found 'identifier'
>   1>e:\my documents\visual studio 2008\projects\hello\hello\hello.cpp(1) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: '': No such file or directory

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Use double quotes `"` to surround `stdafx.h` and `Hello world!\n`

Currently you are using some [inverted quotes/quotation marks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark).

Comment: thanks for pointing that out , but i tried it and it doesnt work unfortunately

Comment: a whole new set actually : 1>e:\my documents\visual studio 2008\projects\hello\hello\hello.cpp(2) : warning C4067: unexpected tokens following preprocessor directive - expected a newline
1>e:\my documents\visual studio 2008\projects\hello\hello\hello.cpp(5) : error C2065: '“Hello' : undeclared identifier
1>e:\my documents\visual studio 2008\projects\hello\hello\hello.cpp(5) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'world'

Comment: and : 1>e:\my documents\visual studio 2008\projects\hello\hello\hello.cpp(5) : error C2065: 'world' : undeclared identifier
1>e:\my documents\visual studio 2008\projects\hello\hello\hello.cpp(5) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '!'
1>e:\my documents\visual studio 2008\projects\hello\hello\hello.cpp(5) : error C2017: illegal escape sequence
1>e:\my documents\visual studio 2008\projects\hello\hello\hello.cpp(5) : error C2065: 'n”' : undeclared identifier

Comment: @Anant: You also need to change the quotes around your `Hello world!\n`

Answer (score 4):

If you copied the code example directly from your source code, it seems that you have Unicode curly double quotes ( Unicode | U+201C  (decimal: 8220) ) when the compiler is expecting ASCII double quotes ( ASCII | 34   (hex: 22  |  octal: 0042  |  binary: 00100010) | Unicode | U+0022  (decimal: 34) )